# update records where null from subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been trying to get this query to work for the longest and I figure maybe I am not looking at it right. Basically I have records in a table where I am trying to locate where their is data conflicts. Example I have a field that is not a primary key, but I want to find all occurrences where the other columns data are not the same
 example:
So basically if I have two johns and they both have different addresses I want to update my table to make them have the same, even if one John has a null address. I came up with

```
UPDATE Table
SET Address =Address 
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Address != Address
```

but this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Please give your table(s) structure and show how you are joining.

Comment: You need to be able to link the two tables using the primary key, otherwise you will update all the rows where the address does not match. Post the table structures to make it easier for people to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: "they both have different addresses I want to update my table to make them have the same" OK, 2 different addresses. How do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I only wanted to know for personal preference how to overwrite one, but the one I am going to do is overwrite only the nulls

Comment: There exist only one table, basically I am trying to overwrite table in the same table where column value John has an address for one record John but not for other record John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
    SET address = t2.address
    FROM YourTable t1
        INNER JOIN YourTable t2
            ON t1.Name = t2.Name
    WHERE t1.PrimaryId <> t2.PrimaryId
        AND t1.address IS NULL
        AND t2.address IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to update Table2 with Table1 values and that there exists a column called `ID` on both tables that links the data:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Address = t1.Address
FROM Table2 as t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

UPDATE:

Based on your comment, if you only want to update the null values in table2 then use this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.Address = t1.Address
FROM Table2 as t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t2.Address is null
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to update duplicate records rather than just removing them?

Comment: that doesn't work, but the reason I am doing this is to eliminate the records that are null(data conflicts), those are not the only columns that exist in the table

Comment: @Joe's answer is probably what you want.  That said, it sounds like you have some weird architecture that might cause problems down the road.

Comment: thats the thing, I am fixing the architecture, because it has problems now from the way it was built